# Javascript string replacement (a more elegant way)

Tags: javascript

I have a string:

```
var myString = 'Some text {{more text}} next text';
```

And I am trying to replace `{{` and `}}` with `<span>` and `</span>`.

I have done this by doing:

```
var myString = 'Some text {{more text}} next text';
myString = myString.replace(/\{\{/, '<span>');
myString = myString.replace(/\}\}/, '</span>');
console.log(myString);
```

However this seems messy, is there an approach that is more elegant?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Regex isn´t necessary here, you shorter and cleaner

```
myString = myString.replace('{{', '<span>');
myString = myString.replace('}}', '</span>');
```

Another possibility (thx @*Artyom Neustroev* for comment):

```
myString = myString.replace('{{', '<span>').replace('}}', '</span>');
```

Comment: You can also chain the `.replace` function

Comment: @ArtyomNeustroev: it´s one of possibilities, this one looks better, at least in my view.

Comment: One advantage to using the regexp is that you can control whether to replace only the first occurrence or all of them (with /.../g). I think with strings you systematically replace all occurrences (which is likely what the question was about)

Comment: @manuBrion: regex is slower, so when beingalex has string with only one pair of brackets, we can use replace without regex.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use regex, here you have an example;

```
var myStrippedStr = myString.replace(/(.*){{(.*)}}(.*)/, '$1<span>$2</span>$3');
```

Answer (score 1):

This should also work, I am not getting a need to escape.

```
myString = myString.replace(/{{/,'<span>').replace(/}}/,'</span>')
```

There are benefits of using regexp like `global` and `case-sensitive` match.

Answer (score 0):

This works also:

```
myString.split('{{').join('<span>').split('}}').join('</span>')
```

No regex required - and this has the added benefit of doing a kind of "replace all" as well.